# How do I store tabular data in MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I am having trouble figuring out how to store my data in access. I need to keep track of students test results and comments.

for example

```
student no 12345
subjet: math
result: (avg of all the tests)

test#     result   retest   comments
------------------------------------
test_1    50%       70%     lalalala
test_2    60%       65%     lalalala
test_3    75%       NA      lalalala
test_4    80%       NA      lalalala
test_5    90%       NA      lalalala
```

how could I make a table to store that info for all the students and different subjects?

any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? Also, are you asking for help with the table design, or do you not know how to create a table in Access?

Comment: No its not homework, on teacher-parent meetings, i want to be able to show a visual representation of how a student is doing. Was asking help with table designs. Looks like I need to make multiple tables.

Comment: You might like to read http://r937.com/relational.html

Answer (score 0):

I would have one table with your students, a table with the subjects and then another table that contained the test results:

```
TableStudents
StudentNo
StudentName

TableSubject
SubjectId
SubjectName

TableResults
StudentNo
SubjectId
TestNumber
Result
Retest
Comment
```

In your TableStudents, you would have one entry for each student. The TableSubject, you would have one entry for each subject. The last table the PrimaryKey would contain the StudentNo, SubjectId and testNumber.

Answer (score 0):

You will begin this project by creating one table to hold each kind of thing you need to work with.  In your example, that sounds like one table for students, one for subjects, and one for test results.

You will make sure that each table has one or more columns that uniquely identifies each row you put into the table.  For students, that might be a StudentID or government ID number of some kind.

You will than make sure that each table has columns that help you connect each row in that table to rows in other tables that relate to it.  For instance, if you use a student id column in the students table, that same column will probably have to be in the test results column so that you know which student each test result applies to.

Once you've developed a set of tables and relationships like this, you can post another question seeking people's comments on your work.